# Read each rows before sending using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have following table inside a form

```
<form>
    <table id="Table1" class="appendGrid ui-widget">
        <thead class="ui-widget-header">
            <tr>
                <td class="ui-widget-header" style="width: 32px;"></td>
                <td class="ui-widget-header">SupCo</td>
                <td class="ui-widget-header">Number</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="ui-widget-content">
            <tr id="tblAppendGrid_Row_1">
                <td class="ui-widget-content first">1</td>
                <td class="ui-widget-content">
                    <input type="text" id="tblAppendGrid_SupCo_1" name="SupCo" maxlength="100" style="width: 160px;"></td>
                <td class="ui-widget-content">
                    <input type="text" id="tblAppendGrid_Number_1" name="Number" maxlength="4" style="width: 40px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tblAppendGrid_Row_2">
                <td class="ui-widget-content first">2</td>
                <td class="ui-widget-content">
                    <input type="text" id="tblAppendGrid_SupCo_2" name="SupCo" maxlength="100" style="width: 160px;"></td>
                <td class="ui-widget-content">
                    <input type="text" id="tblAppendGrid_Number_2" name="Number" maxlength="4" style="width: 40px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tblAppendGrid_Row_3">
                <td class="ui-widget-content first">3</td>
                <td class="ui-widget-content">
                    <input type="text" id="tblAppendGrid_SupCo_3" name="SupCo" maxlength="100" style="width: 160px;"></td>
                <td class="ui-widget-content">
                    <input type="text" id="tblAppendGrid_Number_3" name="Number" maxlength="4" style="width: 40px;"></td>
            </tr>
                   <button  role="button" class="ui-button" id="btnSave" type="button"></button>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

I am trying to read each row(tr) and submit it using ajax function.

```
$('#btnSave').button().click(function () {
    var rowData = $(document.forms[0]).serializeArray();
    $.each(rowData, function (i, field) {
        var oData = {
            "SupCo": field.SupCo.value,
            "Number": field.Number.value        
        };                               
    $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: "./api/updateDb?Id=" + Id +"&",
       data: oData,
       Sucess: alert("Record UdpateSucessfully.")                    
    });   
});
```

Problem I am having is, when i try to serlializeArray, it just is one long string and doesn't save in object. My goal is to get each row as an object or read nearest tr, so I can submit it to update db. 
Any ideas how I can do that? Help pleaseeeeee

Comment: `Sucess` is not an event, `success` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this (assuming the id you want is in the first column) :

```
$('#btnSave').button().click(function () {
    var rows = $('form tbody>tr');
    $.each(rows, function () {
        var oData = {
            "SupCo": $(this).find('input[name="SupCo"]').val(),
            "Number": $(this).find('input[name="Number"]').val()       
        };                               
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "./api/updateDb?Id=" + $(this).find('td.first').text() +"&",
            data: oData,
            success: alert("Record UdpateSucessfully.")                    
        });   
    });
});
```

But maybe it would be better (depending of your needs) to send only one single ajax request with the whole data of all rows than many of them (one by row). Something like :

```
$('#btnSave').button().click(function () {
    var oData = {
        'rows': []
    };
    var rows = $('form tbody>tr');
    $.each(rows, function () {
        oData.rows.push({
            "Id": $(this).find('td.first').text(),
            "SupCo": $(this).find('input[name="SupCo"]').val(),
            "Number": $(this).find('input[name="Number"]').val()       
        });
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "./api/updateDb",
        data: oData,
        success: alert("Record UdpateSucessfully.")                    
    }); 
});
```

And make a loop in your server-side script :

```
foreach ($_POST['rows'] as $row) {
    $id = $row['Id'];
    $supCo = $row['SupCo'];
    $number = $row['Number'];
    /* your script */
}
```

Comment: Sending per row might be better if they are independent, as it would reduce overhead on single request and allow partial update if specific row fails to save. Speaking as someone who works on an app that could really benefit from such an approach.

Comment: Indeed, it depends of the needs. I just provide it as an alternative. Thanks though.